# Axis java web service: connect to database on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis

I have an axis java web service, which I use for inserting and receiving data from database. As far as I know, constructor of web service is called only when client connects, and when it disconnects, a "destructor" is called. So every time a client connects to receive or insert data, I need to run method connectToDatabase(). How can I connect only once, when web service is started, and when client connects simply insert/receive data? Is there any special way to do it in Eclipse?

Comment: You should definitely consider using datasources with connection pools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object which will be instantiated when your application first starts up.  To do that you can use spring and expose your web service implementation class as a spring bean. Than create some king of object which will have a method `connectToDatabase()`, call that method in this object's constructor or specify it as an init method and declare this object in spring configuration. When application is being deployed spring creates that object for you and call this method only once.

To expose axis web service as spring bean do the following:

In axis `server-config.wsdd` file specify this:

```
<service name="YouServiceName" provider="java:SPRING" style="wrapped" use="literal">
```

Attribute `provider="java:SPRING"` tells axis to that the implementation class is exposed as spring bean.

Hope this helps.